# Need openCv library for android

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition

I need to create an app in android which would detect and recognize human faces. And I wish to use OpenCV. Googled a lot but not able to get OpenCV library. Can any one can provide me the link from where I can download OpenCV library?

Comment: @ThiefMaster as I was new for opencv i have posted that link..but now I have edited my answer which is an exact answer to my question,please undelete it..I have been warned to get banned.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.6/OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk-r2.zip/download

Answer (score 2):

Cmon man, classic JFGI
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android

search words: "opencv android"

Comment: He may want a precompiled library. Anyhow, there are several good tutorials about this topic.

Comment: Roman - Thanks a lot..But I have visited this link already and download the said packages..but can't find any .jar files so that I can attach it and use it for my android package.

Comment: SatelliteSD - I have read out many tutorials..but not able to get my question answered..And i m looking for openCv.jar file. and small correction pls use 'She' instead of 'He'. Thanks  :-)

Comment: Hi, there may be a possibility that there is no jar file for opencv, but that doesn't mean you cannot use it in android, I think you should just follow the instructions and see what happens, and not be locked on finding JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the examples in the /opencv/android folder. There is a jar you can get here http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

The problem is, the way you interact with OpenCV in android is via JNI wrappers. I think the binary only has a few important ones. In the later tutorials I think they tell you how to write new wrappers.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The link/tuturial you're looking for is at

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html#android-binary-package

The download (OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin.tar.bz2) contains an Android project (OpenCV-2.3.1)which you can import into eclipse. You then add this project as an android Library to the project where you want to use OpenCV functionaltiy.